# AngularJS suspend $watch for internal updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a directive which has a two way binding to bring in the text specification for a flow chart which is used to generate the actual objects (steps and connections) inside the directive. I have a $watch set up inside the directive to allow the controller to send in a new specification (e.g. loading a new chart), but I also want to have the directive make changes to the specification in response to user action (e.g. deleting a connection) so that the controller can save the changed specification.

I have a function in the directive which converts the chart objects back into a text specification, but if I simply replace the specification scope variable with the updated value, the original watch sees a change (which it thinks might have come from the controller) and so reloads the chart from the specification. This has the effect of breaking things like dragging elements around because the elements are being removed from the DOM and replaced by new ones.

What I would like to be able to do is temporarily suspend the $watch while I make my internal changes, or in some other way avoid the watch from triggering when the directive makes changes to it, only going off when the controller makes changes from outside. I tried to unbind and rebind the watch around making the change, but because the actual checking happens elsewhere in the cycle that does not work. An alternative solution I could use is to have two variables passed between the controller and directive, one going each way, but that is somewhat inelegant. Any better suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Hmm, first you would need to provide some code :). Especially if you say that the "check" is done outside the cycle :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do this, usually my $watch looks something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('MyVar',function(newval,oldval) {
    if (oldval == newval) return;
    if (newval == $scope.internalval) return;
    // process here
})
```

For precisely the reason you outline.  I don't believe you can turn the $watch off, so before I make an internal update to the watched variable, I update a tracking version of the variable to make sure I don't get infinitely-recursing changes.  It seems like a pain, but the watched variables are finite and I always use a setter function so the code updating the internal value is only written once

Comment: Thanks, that did the job perfectly